# Why don't they jump forward in time to find this character

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In DC's "Legends of Tomorrow", we know that

> Carter is killed.

However, since

> Carter gets revived into a new life whenever he dies

Why doesn't the team just jump forward in time to

> when he is revived and grown up so he can rejoin the team?

Comment: Presumably Carter isn't like Vandal Savage and isn't making a huge impact, so it might be that they don't know where to go because Gideon can't locate him. Also raises the question of when he would be re-born; since this is the first time he's died while time travelling, who knows what would happen? Is his rebirth relative to the year in which he died, even though he's from 2016?

Comment: They could use Kendra, since apparently they are "drawn to eachother". Regardless of when Carter gets a new life, it is at some point in the future (safe to say, his new life exist at some point past either 1970 or 2016).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the source for this right now, but from what I remember, they can reincarnate only after both of them are dead in a particular reincarnation.

Thus, in the current time-frame, Carter will not be reborn till Kendra dies too.(I know.. SO grim)

This would probably explain why they are the same age(Same as in, the same age that they were when the first died) in all the reincarnations shown on-screen.

Comment: Seems resonable. This would also make it more difficult to find either of them since neither of them would be able to help the team to find the other.

Comment: I have to note after watching Season 1 of LoT: There is a future Carter that's been found by someone, so why couldn't the team do it?